# change value of name attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I print data in table and try to change name of specific `hidden field` but i cant my code is as below

```
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </th>
                <th>sr no</th>
                <th>seller</th>
                <th>shape</th>
                <th>size</th>
                <th>color</th>
                <th>discount</th>
                <th>client</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($cod_details as $cod)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="{{ $cod->id }}" value="{{ $cod->id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $cod->report_no }}" id="{{ $cod->report_no }}" name="" class="report">
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $cod->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $cod->seller }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $cod->shape }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $cod->size }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $cod->color }}</t
                    <td>{{ $cod->discount }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $cod->client }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

this shows all details in table and working perfect.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                $(this).closest('input[type="hidden"]').attr('name','report_no[]');

            }
            else{

            }
        });
    });
```

I try to add `name = report_no[]` on checked of checkbox but i cant.

Comment: `$(this).next('input[type="hidden"]')`  or `$(this).closest('td').find('input[type="hidden"]')`

Comment: Or `$(this).closest('td').find('input[type="hidden"]')`

Comment: @gurvinder372: `click` works too, with checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks @Satpal it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the very next element in the DOM, immediately after the checkbox. So in your handler:

```
var input = $(this).next();
```

...will give you a jQuery wrapper for that `input` field.

Side note: `if($(this).prop("checked") == true){` is a very long-winded way to write `if (this.checked)`, I'd just use that. :-)

So:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).next().attr('name','report_no[]');
    }
    else {

    }
});
```

If you want to clear it when the checkbox is unchecked, then:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(this).next().attr("name", this.checked ? "report_no[]" : "");
});
```